# Finite Cohomology and free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F$ be a finitely generated nonabelian free profinite group, $p$ a prime number, $L \lhd_o F$ with $[F : L]$ coprime to $p$, $N \lhd_c^\infty F$ contained in $L$ with $L/N$ pro-$p$, and $N \leq H \leq_c^\infty F$. Suppose that there exists a discrete $H$-module structure on $M = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $H^1(H,M)$ is finite.

Must $L/N$ be free pro-$p$?

The case when one can take $M = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and trivial as an $H$-module (every element of $H$ acts as an identity) and $H^1(H,M) = \{0\}$ is already of interest.

In this special case, I want to show that $L/N$ is free pro-$p$ given that $\text{Hom}(H,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: I forgot to say that I assume $[F :  N] = \infty$

Comment: @HJRW: To get a feeling try to take $L = F$ and $H = N$. In this case I am quite sure this works.

Comment: But why can't you take $H=F$?

Comment: You are right, I need to assume that $[F : H] = \infty$ as well.

Comment: I see why you're interested in Greenberg's theorem!